# How to remove an array element from an Arraylist without using index in Java

Tags: java

I want to remove the array `int[]{1,2,3,4]` from the `list`.

We can remove it from the `list` by the code `list.remove(2)` (2 is the index). But how we can remove this array by the function `remove(Object obj)`
I thank you so much.

```
List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("hello");
    list.add(10);
    list.add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

Comment: Bad form to use untyped Lists

Comment: @ScaryWombat are you able to change the duplicate message or remove it since the OP commented on  my answer they needed to remove an int array?

Comment: I did not mark it as a dupe, @robby did, so I think it would be polite to ask him.

Comment: If you have a reference to the same array, you can pass that to `remove(Object)`. Otherwise, you are better off using `remove(int)` and passing the appropriate index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, What's the issue here? Just cast the Int to an object.

```
list.remove((Object) 10);
```

Since you said you want to remove the int[] which wasn't specified in the question you can do so like this

Okay so I have put together a method.

```
public void removeIntArray(List list, int[] toRemove) {
    ListIterator listIterator = list.listIterator();
    while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
        Object object = listIterator.next();
        if (object instanceof int[]) {
            int[] ints = (int[]) object;
            if (Arrays.equals(ints, toRemove)) {
                listIterator.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just call it as

```
removeIntArray(list, new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
```

Comment: My aim is to remove the array {1,2,3,4}

Comment: Edited my answer, There you go :)

Comment: You'd have to pass the same array to `remove(Object)`, not a similar new array. Arrays do not support value-equality.

Comment: I have no right to downvote you. that should be someone else.

Comment: @khelwood Ah, I never did this before so I thought it would be the same. I will come up with a solution.

Comment: @khelwood I have updated my answer, Can you verify if that will still give errors?

Comment: @ SamzSakerz I hope to hear from you soon. I thank you so much

Comment: @SamzSakerz No I can't, but you can compile and run it yourself and check.

Comment: @khelwood. There's no error when I compile it. Just curious if it can break at certain times.

Comment: Still wondering why someone downvoted me, Was it you @khelwood?

Comment: @SamzSakerz No, not me. I wouldn't worry too much about one down vote.

Comment: @khelwood not worried about down-vote, Just mildly annoyed because the down-voter said nothing as a feedback, So I don't know what to improve on my answer.